# How to send email via ionic app? $cordovaEmailComposer is showing Is not Available

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

I want send a mail from ionic app but the code is not working.
Installed below plugin using [this link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

below is my code for controller

```html
.controller('EmailSenderCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {

  $scope.sendFeedback = function(){
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
      function (isAvailable) {
        // alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable;
        cordova.plugins.email.open({
          to:      'test@xyz.com',
          cc:      'jane@doe.com',
          subject: 'Feedback',
          body:    'This app is awesome'
        });
      }
    );
  };

  $scope.sendContactMail = function() {
    alert("sendContactMail call");
    //Plugin documentation here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/emailComposer/

 
$cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
   // is available
   alert("is available");
 }, function () {
   // not available

   alert("Not available");
 });

  var email = {
    to: 'abhay.sharma@ratufa.com',
    cc: 'admin@ingredientapp.info',
    bcc: ['admin@ingredientapp.info'],
    subject: 'Cordova Icons',
    body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
    isHtml: true
  };

 $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
   // user cancelled email
   alert("Email Not compose");
 });
 alert("mail send");

  };

})
```

and this is my html

```html
<div class="send-email">
        <button class="button button-outline button-block featured" ng-controller="EmailSenderCtrl" ng-click="sendContactMail()">
          Send us an email
        </button>
      </div>
```

Having problem with **$cordovaEmailComposer** is showing **Is not Available**.
Please help me for fix it. Thanks

Comment: Why dont you move these kind of things to service level ? It's better if leave it to handle on service level.

Comment: @CharithaGoonewardena it still not working .

Comment: No buddy, i just asked to create email function with smtp server. something like that. What is the backend language you are using ? is it C# ? if so i can help

Comment: Thanks for response . I am not using C# for backend and i can't  move these kind of things to service level because it does't full fill our requirement. Have any suggestion or modification in above code ?